# Binding to multiple objects

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

In my current situation, I have a list to display in my app. This list should be based on two things. Description, and a color, which is based on the current state of each element. The challenge is that description and color are set in each their own tables. Is there a way to set my itemsource/ bindingcontext to two different objects/ tables? Or is there a different way to solve this problem?

This is my XAML file binding to the table where the description is accessible:

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="postListView" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

In my code behind postListview is set to one of the tables:

`PostListView.itemSource = _chekc;`

I am not able to set two different itemsources, thus not able to bind to color in my other table _answer.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem:  you have to display a list that is a combination of data from more than one table.  The fact that you cannot set the ItemsSource to more than one source is not a bug in the ListView that has to be worked around...it is a limitation in your design...you need to construct a view model that properly handles this situation.

So one way of doing this is to have a PostRowView class that is a pairing of color and description from your two tables and a ObservableCollection that manages the PostRowViews.  You bind the ItemsSource of the ListView to the observable collection.

Comment: the most important thing to highlight from this answer is the need/requirement to properly create a View. Most people working with WPF follow the MVVM frontend architecture. Have a look at it, if not already

Comment: Convention is to call this a ViewModel. And yes, a ViewModel should filter/combine/preprocess data to simplify the View.

Comment: This answers my question! Do any of you have a example on how to pair color and description to the PostRowView class?